Proving that $f(x) = (2^x-1)^{1/x}+ (2^x+3^x-1)^{1/x}$ is increasing for $x \in [1, 2]$
I want to show that the function $f: [1, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $$f(x) = (2^x-1)^{1/x}+ (2^x+3^x-1)^{1/x}$$ is increasing for $x \in [1, 2]$. By plotting it this seems to be true, however I have a hard time working with the derivative.

Some thoughts.
Remark. You may plot all the inequalities in this answer to get some impression. A rigorous proof still involves some work. I think it is doable.
We have
\begin{align*}
 f'(x) &= (2^x - 1)^{1/x}\left(\frac{2^x \ln 2}{x(2^x - 1)} - \frac{\ln(2^x - 1)}{x^2}\right) \\
 &\qquad - (2^x + 3^x - 1)^{1/x}\left(\frac{\ln(2^x + 3^x - 1)}{x^2} - \frac{2^x\ln 2 + 3^x \ln 3}{x(2^x + 3^x - 1)}\right).
\end{align*}
Fact 1. It holds that, for all $x\in [1, 2]$,
$$ (2^x - 1)^{1/x}\left(\frac{2^x \ln 2}{x(2^x - 1)} - \frac{\ln(2^x - 1)}{x^2}\right)
\ge \frac{\ln \frac{256}{27}}{x^2\sqrt 3}.$$
(The proof is given at the end.)
Fact 2. It holds that, for all $x\in [1, 2]$,
$$ \frac{\ln \frac{256}{27}}{x^2\sqrt 3}
\ge (2^x + 3^x - 1)^{1/x}\left(\frac{\ln(2^x + 3^x - 1)}{x^2} - \frac{2^x\ln 2 + 3^x \ln 3}{x(2^x + 3^x - 1)}\right).$$
(The proof is given at the end.)
By Facts 1-2, we have $f'(x) \ge 0$ on $[1, 2]$.

Proof of Fact 1.
Fact A1. It holds that, for all $x\in [1, 2]$,
$$(2^x - 1)^{1/x} \ge (\sqrt{3} - 1)(x - 1) + 1.$$
Fact A2. It holds that, for all $x\in [1, 2]$,
$$\ln(2^x - 1) \le \ln{3} + \frac{4\ln 2}{3}(x-2)
- \frac{2\ln^2 2}{9}(x-2)^2.$$
By Facts A1 and A2, it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &[(\sqrt{3} - 1)(x - 1) + 1] \\
 &\qquad \times\left(\frac{2^x \ln 2}{x(2^x - 1)} - \frac{\ln{3} + \frac{4\ln 2}{3}(x-2)
  - \frac{2\ln^2 2}{9}(x-2)^2}{x^2}\right)\\
 \ge{}& \frac{\ln \frac{256}{27}}{x^2\sqrt 3}. \tag{A1}
\end{align*}
$\phantom{2}$
Proof of Fact 2.
Fact B1. It holds that, for all $x\in [1, 2]$,
$$(2^x + 3^x - 1)^{1/x} \le (2\sqrt{3} - 4)(x - 1) + 4.$$
Fact B2. It holds that, for all $x\in [1, 2]$,
$$\ln(2^x + 3^x - 1) \le \ln{12} + \left(\frac{\ln 2}{3} + \frac{3\ln 3}{4}\right)(x - 2).$$
By Facts B1 and B2, it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\ln \frac{256}{27}}{x^2\sqrt 3} &\ge [(2\sqrt{3} - 4)(x - 1) + 4]\\
 &\qquad \times \left(\frac{\ln{12} + \left(\frac{\ln 2}{3} + \frac{3\ln 3}{4}\right)(x - 2)}{x^2} - \frac{2^x\ln 2 + 3^x \ln 3}{x(2^x + 3^x - 1)}\right). \tag{B1}
\end{align*}
